# Windows 11 Remote Desktop Doesn't Remember Domain Name / Removes Domain name every time

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm using windows 11 and I remote into a PC which is in a different domain.

I type in the username with the domain name, but when I click connect the domain is stripped from the username and I need to click "More choices" each time and re-type the username with the domain name.

[Image of the Remote Desktop input vs the login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvpzW.png)

Is there any way to get windows remote connection to remember the DOMAIN\ part of my username so that I don't have to always click more choices and re-type my domain.

Comment: In Windows RDP, in the pull down (extra settings), have you checked (enabled)  "Allow me to save credentials" ?    Is this Pro or Home?

Comment: I have checked that before and it still removes the domain. I believe it's Enterprise

Comment: My organization recently put this in place.  In my case, it is "credentials guard".  IT MAKES ME NUTS!  What did I do?  I started using MobaXTerm to remote in (YES, it is Microsoft RDC.. try it).  Not only will it cache everything, it has other cool features that the windows client does not.  Example?  The MobaXTerm client window can change the resolution to match the window size with the click of a button in the middle of a session without disconnect/reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and after trying numerous things, I finally got something to work. I noticed that when typing in `DOMAIN\user` and hitting "Connect", `DOMAIN\` was being truncated. On a whim, I tried `DOMAIN\DOMAIN\user`, and only the first `DOMAIN\` was truncated, leaving `DOMAIN\user` as the connecting user, which worked perfectly.

*Then* I was annoyed that even though I had successfully connected, it reverted back to `DOMAIN\user` every time I opened Remote Desktop, so I'd have to manually type it every time. I came up with two solutions to this problem:

1. Once you've typed `DOMAIN\DOMAIN\user` as your username, click the "Save" button to overwrite `Default.rdp`. Then, you can manually launch `Desktop.rdp` to make the connection. The downside is that instead of presenting you with the normal Remote Desktop window where you can change servers/options/etc., it immediately initiates a connection to the default server. This may be fine for your usage.
2. Modify `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers\<serverName>\UsernameHint` in the registry to prepend the extra `DOMAIN\` to the value. With this option, you can simply launch Remote Desktop as before, and your pre-populated username will show as `DOMAIN\DOMAIN\user`, but will connect as `DOMAIN\user`. NOTE: After you connect, Windows 11 will overwrite the `UsernameHint` registry value with the truncated `DOMAIN\user` value; to get around this, you will *also* need to right-click the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers\<serverName>` key, choose "Permissions..." and *uncheck* "Full Control" from the "Allow" column (leaving "Read" checked) for your user.

This is obviously some weird new behavior in Windows 11, and could be a bug, but this is the workaround I came up with for now.

Answer (score 0):

I did ultimately find an alternative for my case. My username is also associated with a work email.

Instead of doing `DOMAIN\user`, I was able to just use my work email like `user@domain.com`.

That will be saved in remote desktop and it will know the domain based off the email.